# String Comparison with a Format - Python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I wanted to check if user has entered the input in particular order or not. Basically i wanted user to input date in format like this

```
%d/%m/%y %H:%M
```

Is there any way i can compare string input with the above format in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import time
time.strptime("01/01/09 12:23", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

This will raise ValueError if the string doesn't match:

```
time.strptime("01/01/09 12:234", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
time.strptime("01-01-09 12:23", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

By the way, please don't bring back two-digit years--use %Y if at all possible.

Comment: Your method works too, I suppose.  *sigh*  In fact, it's likely better than mine for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for... Regular Expressions! Have a look at the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-re.html). What you want is simple enough that it would be fairly trivial to just hand you the regex for it, but you should learn to use them yourself.

OK, for this job, the `strptime` answer is better.  But for the general case of making sure a string matches up with a format, regular expressions are generally the way to go.

Comment: Yes, the regex for valid dates would be pretty bad and depend on what format you wanted to allow. `strptime` is a lot more flexible for a lot less code (on our part)